# how to check if content type is

Tags: 7, commerce

I ve got 2  type of commerce product.1 is the product the other is another type of product commerce.
I want to check if the product type is then you can do something if not do another thing.

Notes:

- I've got a 1 product type is a shipping and the other product type the option Both of them are cumulated on the commerce cart i want to to check if the product type is a shipping and the other is an option .the option on the cart i want it will be unable to remove on the cart and the shipping product can be remove to select another shipping product . i am on drupal 7 with commerce 1.
- my question is to check the product type and be able to block the button remove on the cart.
- only if the product type is a shipping the button can be remove on the cart.
- delete-line-item btn btn-sm btn-default form-submit i want it will be removable only if the product type is a shipping.
- views-view-field--commerce-cart-block--default--edit-delete.tpl.php ont this i want if the product type is a shipping the button can be remove but the other product (the options) cannot be removable.
- i ve create a template from views-view-field--commerce-cart-block--default--edit-delete.tpl.php and  but i don t know how to set this button enable only if the product type is a shipping product.
- (Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line Item : suppress button.

Comment: Please give some more context to your question.  In what part of your code you want to check about the type of commerce product ? Show us some code samples.  What have you tried ?

Comment: hello i ve got a 1 product type is a shipping and the other product type the option Both of them are cumulated on the commerce cart i want to to check if the product type is a shipping and the other is an option .the option on the cart i want it will be unable to remove on the cart and the shipping product can be remove to select another shipping product . i am on drupal 7 with commerce 1. my question is to check the product type and be able to block the button remove on the cart

Comment: only if the product type is a shipping the button can be remove on the cart

Comment: delete-line-item btn btn-sm btn-default form-submit i want it will be removable only if the product type is a shipping

Comment: views-view-field--commerce-cart-block--default--edit-delete.tpl.php ont this i want if the product type is a shipping the button can be remove but the other product 
(the options) cannot be removable

Comment: i ve create a template from views-view-field--commerce-cart-block--default--edit-delete.tpl.php and 
<?php print $output; ?> but i don t know how to set this button enable only if the product type is a shipping product

Comment: (Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line Item : suppress button

Comment: So please update and reformat your question to be complete, and look arround how other people are formatting their questions to get great responses, at the moment your question is incomplete I am afraid.